# jQuery submit button does not respond

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jquery to submit a form but I does not respond to the click event.
This is a live demo.
   http://jsfiddle.net/H7FTX/1/

```
<form>        
         <input type="button" name="sendBtn"  value=" send "  class="sendBtn"  />   

    </form>

    (function() {
      $('.sendBtn').click(function() {

          alert('OKKKK');

        });
    });
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) You missed to add `$`.

(2) On checking your JSFiddle ***you missed to add jQuery library***(available at left-top corner in JSFiddle)

```
$(function () {
    $('.sendBtn').click(function () {
        alert('OKKKK');
    });
});
```

Better change your JS like below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sendBtn').on('click', function () {
        alert('OKKKK');
    });
});
```

[**Update fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/H7FTX/5/)

Comment: Thank you. It is working now but I want to ask you why is the second method better than the first one?

Comment: @Gham `.on()` helps to  attach an event handler function for one or more events.  `$(function () {` and `$(document).ready(function () {` are **equivalent**. But `$(document).ready` is **more readable** :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

Your Fiddle is not importing jquery. Also you should add the `$` to the begin of your script to signify jquery document ready.

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/H7FTX/4/)

```
$(function() {
  $('.sendBtn').click(function() {

      alert('OKKKK');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you just missing **$** before *function*. Please do the following

```
$(function () {
    $('.sendBtn').click(function () {

        alert('OKKKK');

    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to load jQuery in your HTML and you have to invoke

```
$(function() { 
 ...
});
```

(not just `(function() { ... });`

Comment: `$(function () { ... })` doesn't load jquery. It's an alias to `$(document).ready(function () { ... })` which will call the function till the document is loaded. Though it may solve the problem, but the information is wrong.

Comment: I didn't say ``$(function () { ... })`` will load jquery. I said, the questioner has to load jquery (i.e. include the `<script>` that loads jquery) *and* (afterwards/additionally/also) has to change the javascript snippet. The answer is probably very short but it is not wrong.